# How to Speed Up a Lagging Swift File?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, lag

I have a Swift file in my app that has about 4,500 lines of code, and will likely need to grow to at least 7,000.  The amount, or some sections of this amount of lines, is causing my ability to type in this particular .swift file to lag.  I've tried to clean it up a bit, but much of it is design, front-end code that seems hard to put into other files...

Any advice on how to speed up my ability to type in this .swift file?  It is very annoying, and my other, smaller .swift files in the project do not have this problem.

Comment: Sounds like you need to refactor that class

Comment: Put some code into extensions, view code into dedicated classes, model code (e.g. parsing) into dedicated classes, business code (e.g. API) into dedicated classes. Use storyboards and xibs to move layout code to interface builder. And next time start refactoring once your class reaches 1500 lines (or even less. I would say that 1000 lines is already a lot for a file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other comments have said, you need to refactor your large file into smaller components. This will not only improve compile times, but will also make your code more manageable.

Here are some really great talks about refactoring code specifically for iOS:

[WWDC 2014: Advanced iOS Application Architecture and Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/229/)

[Let's Play: Refactor the Mega Controller!](https://realm.io/news/andy-matuschak-refactor-mega-controller/)

Comment: Obviously, I'm still pretty new to coding... thank you for the fast response and links!  This solved it, but now I need to learn to elegantly refactor..

Comment: Learning to code "well" takes a long time and a lot of practice. These talks really helped me think about designing my code in elegant ways. They key is to try lots of different things and see what works well.